# Cannot find native module 'ExpoCrypto' when using expo-auth-session

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, expo-auth-session, expo-crypto

I'm trying to use expo-auth-session to google signin in my react native application, but when running the code, i'm getting the error:

ERROR  Error: Cannot find native module 'ExpoCrypto'
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.

Already tried expo prebuild, but nothing changed.

```
package.json:
{
  "name": "selvaapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test:types": "tsc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.7.1",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.15",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.4.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "axios": "^1.3.6",
    "eas": "^0.1.0",
    "eas-cli": "^3.15.0",
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-auth-session": "~4.0.3",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.6.0",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.3.1",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-crypto": "~12.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "expo-web-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "firebase": "^9.22.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-dropdown-select-list": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-maps": "1.3.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.19"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@expo/config-plugins": "~6.0.0",
    "@expo/prebuild-config": "~6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.12",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.13",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/styled-components-react-native": "^5.2.1",
    "ts-migrate": "^0.1.35",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to create a development build by running "expo prebuild" and then run it using "expo run -i" instead of using Expo go

Comment: I'm not using expo go